# Power Query - add column quantities based on excel cells

Tags: excel, powerquery

**Problem**

I have a table in Power Query with multiply records for multiply products IDs. I want to be able to add records for different products IDs based on criteria saved in excel cell.

[Excel table with criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa551.png).

[Power Query Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiYOz.png)

In Power Query table 1st column is product ID, 2nd quantity and 3rd location ID.

**Goal**

I want to be able to put product ID numbers into Excel Criteria table (1st picture), for example number 131578 and 141143 so in result it will combine 50 + 24 (2nd and last position in Power Query table) because I added both numbers to excel table and location ID matches as well.

**What I tried**

I googled many results but every solution was based on custom tables and stuff inside the Power Query editor where my conditions are in normal cell. I tried to add exception based on *Get Data From Range/Table* but it works only for 1 condition where I have 10.

**tldr**

I want to add conditions in excel cells, so Power Query will use them to add Product ID A quantity to Product ID B quantity if Location ID is the same.

Comment: Assuming you are using PowerQuery with both tables loaded ... Unpivot the Criteria table to get values into one column. Merge the new Criteria table into the other table. Expand. Filter out the null rows without a match. Group table on location ID, count the location ID field and sum the quantity field. Filter out anything with quantity <2 if you need to (unclear if this last part is a requirement)

Comment: @horseyride you are MVP. This is 99% what I was looking for. I have only one problem, which I was told right now. Now I have Location ID list with sum of quantities of each product listed in my cell list - and this is perfect but on my main table I have also timestamps. Can I add this column so it will sum as it is right now and group by dates?

Comment: Format the timestamp column as a date, and then add it into the original Group along with location ID, that should do it

Comment: Now you are 100% MVP Sir. Works perfectly fine, even better than I was expecting.